# Capturing video from camera with cv2 prints matrices full of zeros

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

I am trying to capture data from the webcam using cv2 in python, but when I print the frame, all the matrices contain only zero values. The camera is working and it's showing the video, no black screens.

This is the code

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a = 0

while True:
    a = a + 1
    check, frame = video.read()
    print(frame)
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
       break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This is how the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2yYq.png)

Comment: The script is working fine. Can you add a sample of trace of the script?

Comment: I added a print screen. I took the code from other users that said the code is perfectly fine, but I have no clue why it's not working for me...

Comment: Just add `if check:` then show the frame. Can you see something?

Comment: Yes, it passes the condition

Comment: Do you have only one camera?

Comment: Make a test: record video with that camera first then put this video file to your code: video = cv2.VideoCapture('myRecordedVideo'). Check if there is still only zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, it works for me.

I'd suggest:

- print one frame every n, for example (100)
- flush the print so you can see the print of the frame while capturing

So, try change the print line to:

```
if a%100 == 0: print(frame, flush = True)
```

Comment: I tried that, and it looks like every printed frame is just zeros

Comment: Can you see the window with the camera stream?

Comment: I tried both on windows and OSX and it's working fine. I get all zeroes only if the webcam is perfectly covered. But you said you can see the camera stream. As you can see in your snapshot, the array is not printed completely, because of it's size. Instead of printing the frame use this line: `print(frame.any(), flush = True)`. If there is some value not zero it should print `True`.

Comment: Looks like there is some non zero there, because it prints true, but I still don't think it's working properly, in other examples the matrices looked completely different, they can't be mainly zero

Comment: Last option I can suggest: run the program from the terminal (in windows `Command Prompt`). For now I run out of ideas since I can not reproduce the problem.